# Rselenium - How to disable images in Firefox profile

Tags: r, windows, firefox, rselenium

How can image downloading be disabled when using Firefox in Rselenium? I want to see if doing so makes a scraping script faster.

I've read the Reselnium package manual including the sections on getFirefoxProfile & makeFirefoxProfile.

I've found [this link that shows how to handle chromedriver](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/105).

I can disable images for a Firefox instance that I manually open in Windows 10 but Rselenium does not appear to use that same profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously you would need to set the appropriate preference (in this case
`permissions.default.image`) however there is now an issue with firefox resetting this value see:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2171

a work around is given:

https://github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/issues/248

implementing this in `RSelenium`:

```
library(RSelenium)
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(permissions.default.image = 2L,
                                 browser.migration.version = 9999L))
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com/ncr")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

# clean up
rm(rD)
gc()
```

Comment: Where can one find the documentation for the Firefox profile options for other settings?

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries contains docs on the about:config entries

Answer (score 1):

Issue: I was attempting to disable images in Firefox for web scraping tasks using R and RSelenium.

Initial Attempt: I first tried using makeFirefoxProfile, but it didn't yield the desired results.

Solution: I eventually worked around this by directly setting the browser parameters, akin to how one would interact with elements while scraping.

```
# Initiate the RSelenium driver for Firefox
client_server <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4444L, chromever = NULL)
driver <- client_server[["client"]]

# Navigate to Firefox's about:config to tweak settings
driver$navigate("about:config")
Sys.sleep(3)

# Accept the warning to access settings
driver$findElement(using = "css selector", value = "#warningButton")$clickElement()

# Search for the image permission setting
webElem <- driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//*[@id='about-config-search']")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("permissions.default.image"))
Sys.sleep(4)

# Modify the image load settings (2 means images won't get loaded)
driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[2]/button")$clickElement()
webElem <- driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "/html/body/table/tr[1]/td[1]/form/input")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("2"))
Sys.sleep(3)

# Confirm changes
driver$findElement(using = "css selector", value = ".primary")$clickElement()
```